# How to load Spring Jpa properties from a txt file

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

In my case, based on conditions different conditions, a `txt` file is created which contains  the database details like database url, username, password, etc. I have to load that file to create the spring jpa database connection database.

Application is in : `D:\Application`
Where the said `txt` falls : `D:\Drop\Files\ExternalProperties`

How to do this ? Is it even possible ?

Comment: Both locations could not be changed

Comment: Maybe try this spring boot profiles. https://zetcode.com/springboot/profile/#:~:text=Spring%20Boot%20profiles,-The%20development%20process&text=Spring%20Boot%20allows%20to%20define,only%20for%20the%20specified%20profile.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use spring profiles (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.0.M1/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html)
which allowes you to create different property / yaml etc. files for storing your properties like follows:

```
application-prod.properties
application-extra.properties
application-dev.properties
application-local.properties
```

Then you can use for example a command line param to indicate which profiles you want to use:

java -jar YOUR.jar --spring.profiles.active=prod,extra

You can use different profiles at the same time and you can also provide a standard set of properties in your application.yaml, so you only have to override the properties that change in your profile based configuration.